# Handler not working as expected in child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am on the last spec in a section of a test from school.

> > select should have an onChange event that submits the new animal

Essentially I can't seem to get the `handleSubmit` function passed into the child, to respond to the changes...
This is the rest of the spec.

```
it('select should have an onChange event that submits the new animal', () => {
  expect(animalSelect.props('select').onChange).to.be.function;

  // choosing a random animal
  let animal = getRandomAnimal();

   // simulating a 'change' event with an event described as the second argument given to `simulate`
   animalSelect.find('select').simulate('change', { target: { value: animal } });

   // the spy sent in should be called with the argument described
   expect(setAnimalSpy.calledWith(animal)).to.be.true;
 });
```

This is the parent component `Exhibit`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AnimalSelect from './AnimalSelect';
import Cage from './Cage';

export default class Exhibit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedAnimal: this.props.selectedAnimal,
    };
    this.setAnimal = this.setAnimal.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  setAnimal(animal) {
    this.setState({ selectedAnimal: animal });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({ selectedAnimal: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedAnimal } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="exhibit">
        <AnimalSelect handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} submitAnimal={this.setAnimal} animals={this.props.animals} />
        <Cage selectedAnimal={selectedAnimal} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the `AnimalSelect` (The child of `Exhibit`) component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// exporting the constructor function (dumb component).
// what is the parameter coming in here?
export default function AnimalSelect(props) {
  // prettier-ignore
  return (
    <form>
      <label>Select an Animal: </label>
      <select onChange={() => props.handleSubmit}>
        {props.animals.map((animal, index) => {
          return (
            <option key={animal} value={animal}>
              {animal}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>;
    </form>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately this is the only error I am getting.

```
    AssertionError: expected false to be true
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try passing the handler directly instead of inside an arrow function `<select onChange={props.handleSubmit>`

Comment: @Sag1v Thanks—Tried it, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you set the event handler to be an anonymous function which returns a reference to a function:

```
<select onChange={() => props.handleSubmit}>
```

You probably intend something more like this:

```
<select onChange={evt => props.handleSubmit(evt)}>
```

This effectively delegates the event handler to the parent component's function, passing the event object along to it. Although I'm uncertain why setting the handler as suggested in the comment didn't work.

Comment: Thanks so much Rich! Unfortunately I tried it and I'm getting this error  `TypeError: props.handleSubmit is not a function` Which doesn't make sense...?

Comment: How is your testing environment set up? If you're using Enzyme, are the components fully or shallow-rendered? It may be that you're seeing an artifact of the test and not the code itself... do the components work as expected in the browser?

Comment: Ahhh, you are correct it, I just popped the browser open and see the images propagating after making a selection in the `<option></option` tag! Thanks! Didn't think to do that—think I'm just so fixated on seeing those lovely green check marks in the console indicating the test passsed!